# Почему не обновляется ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть следующие классы:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding SwitchToTest}">Switch</Button>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Current}" Height="50"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Test.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Test"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock >Test</TextBlock> 
</Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class Test : UserControl
{
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
internal sealed class TestViewModel
{
}

internal sealed class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object current;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get => current;
        set
        {
            current = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Current)));
        }
    }

    ICommand SwitchToTest => new DelegateCommand(() => Current = new TestViewModel());

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Commands:

```
internal abstract class Command : ICommand
{
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public virtual bool CanExecute() => true;

public abstract void Execute();

bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecute();

void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) => Execute();

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

}

```
internal sealed class DelegateCommand : Command
{
private readonly Func<bool> canExecuteMethod;
private readonly Action executeMethod;

public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod) :
    this(executeMethod, () => true)
{
}

public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod,
                       Func<bool> canExecuteMethod
)
{
    this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
}

public override bool CanExecute() => canExecuteMethod();

public override void Execute() => executeMethod();
}
```

Ну и сам Application (при выводе ViewModel будет выводиться соответсвующая View):

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
        <local:Test/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на клавишу содержимое ContentPresenter изменялось, но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте команду публичной и следите за выводом в окно "вывод", там обычно пишутся основные ошибки биндинга.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/292715)

Comment: @Uranus, вроде нормальный ответ, если у ТС свойство с командой непубличное, то привязка действительно не сработает

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да. Сбило с толку вот это: "Сделайте команду публичной **и следите за выводом в окно "вывод"**". Показалось что первая часть подразумевалась не как ответ, а как дополнение ко второй. LiptonDev, можно разбить на два абзаца, в первом ответ, во втором рекомендация.

Comment: @Uranus Хорошо, учту, спасибо.